# This winter is less cold than last one

Tags: comparative-degree

I have a question about the word-usage of "less." Does the sentence "This winter is less cold than last one." make sense?

Comment: Or you could say "This winter is warmer than the last one" and avoid the issue entirely.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a question about the word-usage of "less". Does the sentence ...
>
> - This winter is less cold than last one.
>
> ...  make sense?

The  example sentence is fine - regarding *less*. However, there is a small problem though with "*one*". The word *one* here is not a pronoun ( - although there is a pronoun *one* as well).
The word *one* is a countable noun. Here, *one* is singular, and singular countable nouns in English must have a determiner. Determiners are words like:

- ***a, the, this, that, my, your, no, one, two*** ... , John ***'s*** and so forth.

Here we need *the* because everybody understands which year we are talking about. So the Original Poster's sentence would be perfect like this:

- This winter is less cold than the last one.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think you meant "This winter is less cold than *the* last one." The issue could be avoided by not using *one*, for example "This winter is less cold than last *winter*", since seasons don't need an article.

Comment: @user3169 Erm, oops.  Yes - must watch that cut 'n paste! Have amended -Thanks very much! :) Yes, your other comment's also spot on :)

Comment: +1 because you covered the matter of the determiner/article really well. But I can't help thinking the fact that OP has raised the word "less" in the question title suggests the missing ***the*** really just an incidental error.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing grammatically wrong with 'less cold than', but I think many native speakers would say 'not so/as cold as'.